# Mistakenly changed rack server hdds

Tags: raid

I have an old rack server which is running raid config with 12 hdd in it. One of the junior engineers powered down the server for maintenace. He then swapped 3 hard drives while cleaning the server. Im now in a big mess and the servers wont boot up. The hdd are not labelled. We have data in them and i havent got a clue on how to start the server as it wouldnt boot up. Anyway to get them back online

Comment: do you have any idea what RAID level these were in?

Comment: "Won't boot" is incredibly vague. Tell us what is actually happening.

Comment: Nothing comes up on the screen. Raid 5 in it

Comment: Nothing at all? Not even the BIOS? Not even adfter waiting a minute of two (some servers boot really slow). In that case it might not be (only) a RAID problem. Check if all plugs are connected.

Comment: What type of servers? OS? Hardware? Make/model? Terrible question.

Comment: A RAID problem won't prevent the computer from printing the BIOS to the screen. In order to do any diagnostics you'll need the screen to work first. Check your KVM cables. But even then, we can't help you much until you provide diagnostic info.

Comment: Just to put it out there, after you get past this... I would make sure your junior engineers/admins at least know that you shouldn't mix RAID drives up before letting them do other things on the system (A+ 101)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put the hard drives back in the correct slots.  Since only 3 drives were removed there are only a few combinations to try.  Figure out all the possible combinations and try each one.  When you get it right the server should recognize the raid array.  If other drives are out of order then you may have more combinations to try.  Until you get the right drives in the right slots you are screwed.

Comment: For those playing along at home, there are six possible configurations: 1,2,3 1,3,2 2,1,3 2,3,1 3,1,2 3,2,1

Comment: Factorials! Factorials for everyone!

Comment: It be velly bad to be depending on factorials, 3! for data restoration. Just think, it could be 12! for 479001600 combinations.